# Bound Method Http Request with Google API Python Client Library

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am using Python in order to make a request to the Youtube Data API using the Google API Client Python Library. I don't get any errors, but this same response keeps popping up anytime I try to print out my response results:

```
<bound method HttpRequest.execute of <googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x10af09ca0>>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = '<my_api_key_redacted>'

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

request = youtube.channels().list(part='statistics',forUsername='<my_user_id_redacted>')

response = request.execute

print(response)
```

How do I fix this issue so I can get json results and not this?

Answer (score 2):

I made the same mistake, it's `.execute()`, you're missing the parentheses in the second to last line.

Comment: If I include parentheses in execute then its gives an error, else not. However how to check if the response is correct or not